# After Insert Trigger & WFR Field Update

Tags: trigger, workflow

This is a fresher question.

I am trying to understand the mechanics of SF Order of execution.

Let us assume that there is a custom object "Alpha".

"Alpha" has a custom field "FAlpha".

"FAlpha" is a checkbox field with default value as `false` (unchecked).

If I try to set the field "FAlpha" as `true` via After Insert Trigger, then will the new set value will be available for any WFR which is scheduled to execute whenever it sees the record is edited and subsequently meets the criteria of "FAlpha" being true ?.

I hope I am clear.

Would appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, based on the [Order of Execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) **after insert** trigger runs before any workflow rule.. so when the trigger changes the checkbox field to true, any workflow rule setup to run when the checkbox turns to true will get triggered.

Comment: *after insert* means the record's already committed. Of course, you can try a recursive update to the record, but some care must be taken to avoid infinite recursion.